# Draw a boxplot using an sframe as data source

Tags: python, seaborn, sframe

I'm practicing my ML Classification skills on [The Billionaire Characteristics Database](http://www.iie.com/publications/interstitial.cfm?ResearchID=2917) dataset.

I'm using `sframe` for loading and manipulating the data and `seaborn` for visualization.

In the process of data analysis, I wanted to draw a box plot grouped by a categorical variable, like this one from `seaborn` tutorial:
[image: box plot grouped by categorical value]

In the dataset, there's a `networthusbillion` numerical variable and `selfmade` categorical variable that states whether a billionaire is `self-made` or (s)he has `inherited` the bucks.

When I try to draw a similar box plot using `sns.boxplot(x='selfmade', y='networthusbillion', data=data)`, it throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-f4bd651c2ae7> in <module>()
----> 1 sns.boxplot(x='selfmade', y='networthusbillion', data=billionaires)

/home/iulian/.virtualenvs/data-science-python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.pyc in boxplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, width, fliersize, linewidth, whis, notch, ax, **kwargs)
   2127     plotter = _BoxPlotter(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order,
   2128                           orient, color, palette, saturation,
-> 2129                           width, fliersize, linewidth)
   2130 
   2131     if ax is None:

/home/iulian/.virtualenvs/data-science-python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.pyc in __init__(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, width, fliersize, linewidth)
    420                  width, fliersize, linewidth):
    421 
--> 422         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order)
    423         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
    424 

/home/iulian/.virtualenvs/data-science-python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.pyc in establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
    136             # See if we need to get variables from `data`
    137             if data is not None:
--> 138                 x = data.get(x, x)
    139                 y = data.get(y, y)
    140                 hue = data.get(hue, hue)

AttributeError: 'SFrame' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I tried the following forms to draw the box plot - none of them achieved the result:

```
sns.boxplot(x=billionaires['selfmade'], y=billionaires['networthusbillion'])
sns.boxplot(x='selfmade', y='networthusbillion', data=billionaires['selfmade', 'networthusbillion'])
```

However, I *could* draw a box plot using `sframe`, but without grouping by `selfmade`:

```
sns.boxplot(x=billionaires['networthusbillion'])
```

**So, my question is:** Is there a way to draw a box plot grouped by a categorical variable using an `sframe`? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

By the way, I managed to draw it using a `pandas.DataFrame` using the same syntax (`sns.boxplot(x='selfmade', y='networthusbillion', data=data)`), so maybe grouping using an `sframe` with `seaborn` is just not implemented yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

Grouping using an `sframe` with `seaborn` is just not implemented yet.

---

After digging into the seaborn's source code, I found out that it is designed specifically to work with `pandas.DataFrame`. Taking the absolutelyNoWarranty's suggestion in their answer, I got the following error:

```
TypeError: __getitem__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Taking a look at the `args` in the `get` function on call, there's this data:

```
('gender', 'gender')
```

This happens because of this code in the source code for `BoxPlot`:

```
# See if we need to get variables from `data`
if data is not None:
    x = data.get(x, x)
    y = data.get(y, y)
    hue = data.get(hue, hue)
    units = data.get(units, units)
```

It tries to get the value and uses the same value as a fallback in case it doesn't exist. This causes an error in the `__getitem__()`, because it gets called with `(self, 'gender', 'gender')` arguments.

I tried to rewrite the `get()` function as follows:

```
def get(self, *args):
    return self.__getitem__(args[0]) if args[0] else None  # The `None` is here because the `units` in the source code is `None` for boxplots.
```

And here I got the error that ended my tries:

```
TypeError: 'SArray' object is not callable
```

Taking a look at the source code, it checks whether the `y` data is a `pd.Series` and if not, it converts `y` value into one:

```
if not isinstance(vals, pd.Series):
    vals = pd.Series(vals)

# Group the val data
grouped_vals = vals.groupby(grouper)
```

When executing the `vals.groupby(grouper)` (grouper still being an `SArray` instance), it goes into pandas core workings where the `SArray` is called and the error is thrown. End of story.

Comment: I edited my answer. See if it helps (although at this point it may be too hacky.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `sns.boxplot` expects data to have a `get` method like a Pandas' Dataframe. In Pandas the `get` method returns a single column so it's the same as bracket indexing, i.e. `your_df['your_column_name']`.

The simplest way to work-around this is to call the `to_dataframe` method on your sframe to convert it to a dataframe.

```
sns.boxplot(x='selfmade', y='networthusbillion', data=data.to_dataframe())
```

Alternatively, you can hack around the problem by writing class wrappers around or using [monkey-patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-a-monkey-patch) `get` onto the SFrame class.

```
import numpy as np
import sframe
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# For demostration purposes
def to_sframe(df):
    import sframe
    d = {}
    for key in df.keys():
        d[key] = list(df[key])
    return sframe.SFrame(d)
pd.DataFrame.to_sframe = to_sframe

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

# Monkey patch sframe's get and _CategoricalPlotter's _group_longform
def get(self, *args):
    key = args[0]
    return self.__getitem__(key) if key else None
sframe.SFrame.get = get


def _group_longform(self, vals, grouper, order):
    """Group a long-form variable by another with correct order."""
    #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()

    if type(vals) == sframe.SArray:
        _sf = sframe.SFrame({'vals':vals, 'grouper':grouper})
        grouped_vals = _sf.groupby('grouper', sframe.aggregate.CONCAT('vals'))
        out_data = []
        for g in order:
            try:
                g_vals = np.asarray(grouped_vals.filter_by(g, 'grouper')["List of vals"][0])
            except KeyError:
                g_vals = np.array([])
            out_data.append(g_vals)
        label = ""
        return out_data, label

    ## Code copied from original _group_longform
    # Ensure that the groupby will work
    if not isinstance(vals, pd.Series):
        vals = pd.Series(vals)

    # Group the val data
    grouped_vals = vals.groupby(grouper)
    out_data = []
    for g in order:
        try:
            g_vals = np.asarray(grouped_vals.get_group(g))
        except KeyError:
            g_vals = np.array([])
        out_data.append(g_vals)

    # Get the vals axis label
    label = vals.name

    return out_data, label

sns.categorical._CategoricalPlotter._group_longform = _group_longform


# Plots should be equivalent
#1.
plt.figure()
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
#2.
plt.figure()
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips.to_sframe(),
            order=["Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"])
plt.xlabel("day")
plt.ylabel("total_bill")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The workaround you provided is valid, although I need to investigate how costly is the `to_dataframe()` conversion. The monkey-patching however does not work. I've dived into the `seaborn` source code and its methods are designed to work specifically with dataframes.

Comment: and here's the fast answer from the [`sframe` documentation](https://dato.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.to_dataframe.html#graphlab.SFrame.to_dataframe) for `to_dataframe()`: "This operation will construct a pandas.DataFrame in memory. Care must be taken when size of the returned object is big." So, unfortunately, this is also not a valid option.